# Titanium ListView template conditional rendering

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, listviewitem, titanium-alloy

Does anyone know how it would be possible to conditional render a view in the list view template based on the passed in bindId ?

I have a template which should show a view only if the value if the label that is passed in is not empty.

```
<View class="productBannerLabelWrapper productBanner1">
   <Label class="productBannerLabel" bindId="productBanner1" />
</View>
```

The label has a view around it, because the label needs a collared background which is larger than the label itself.

Thank for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fill you item array you can set the `visible` property like this:

```
var prop = {
  productBanner1: {
     text: "Text",
     visible: (checkValue)?1:0
  }
}
items.push(prop);
$.list_section.items = items;
```

**with Alloy:**

add a databinding to the visible parameter like `productBanner:visible="{isVisible}"`  and use a `dataTransform` to change the module before assigning it:

```
function transformFnc(model) {
    return {
        otherStuff: model.attributes.otherStuff
        isVisible: (checkValue)?1:0
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a collection and alloy databinding to fill the list.
Do you know how that would work with alloy ?

Comment: sure, added an example to the post above. You can use a `dataTransform` function